# how to combine several select statements into one table

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, ssms

I am creating a stored procedure that views the results of polls answers by counting the votes for each choice, however when I run it each select statement is in single table, but I want the result in single table while each select statement is a column, anyone knows how to do it. thanks :)
thats my code:

```
CREATE PROC view_pollresult
 @myemail VARCHAR (30),
 @course_ID INT,
 @poll_ID INT 
 AS
 IF @myemail = (SELECT page_creator FROM Course_pages WHERE course_ID = @course_ID OR @myemail IN (SELECT added_email
 FROM Lecturers_Adds_Academics_Course_page WHERE course_ID = @course_ID))
 BEGIN
 SELECT COUNT(choice) FROM Students_Answers_Polls AS choice1_results
 WHERE poll_ID = @poll_ID AND course_page = @course_ID
 AND choice = (SELECT choice1 FROM Polls WHERE poll_ID = @poll_ID) 
 SELECT COUNT(choice) FROM Students_Answers_Polls AS choice2_results
 WHERE poll_ID = @poll_ID AND course_page = @course_ID
 AND choice = (SELECT choice2 FROM Polls WHERE poll_ID = @poll_ID) 
 SELECT COUNT(choice) FROM Students_Answers_Polls AS choice3_results
 WHERE poll_ID = @poll_ID AND course_page = @course_ID
 AND choice = (SELECT choice3 FROM Polls WHERE poll_ID = @poll_ID) 
 SELECT COUNT(choice) FROM Students_Answers_Polls AS choice4_results
 WHERE poll_ID = @poll_ID AND course_page = @course_ID
 AND choice = (SELECT choice4 FROM Polls WHERE poll_ID = @poll_ID) 
 SELECT COUNT(choice) FROM Students_Answers_Polls AS choice5_results
 WHERE poll_ID = @poll_ID AND course_page = @course_ID
 AND choice = (SELECT choice5 FROM Polls WHERE poll_ID = @poll_ID) 
 END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make it a single statement:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(case when results.choice = p.choice1 then 1 else 0 end) as Choice1Count,
    SUM(case when results.choice = p.choice2 then 1 else 0 end) as Choice2Count,
    SUM(case when results.choice = p.choice3 then 1 else 0 end) as Choice3Count,
    SUM(case when results.choice = p.choice4 then 1 else 0 end) as Choice4Count,
    SUM(case when results.choice = p.choice5 then 1 else 0 end) as Choice5Count
FROM 
    Students_Answers_Polls AS results
    inner join Polls p on
        results.poll_id = p.poll_id
        and results.choice in (p.choice1, p.choice2, p.choice3, p.choice4, p.choice5)
WHERE 
    results.poll_ID = @poll_ID 
    AND course_page = @course_ID
```

Comment: +1 : You don't even actually need the `and results.choice in ()` line.

Comment: @Dems-Didn't know if there were more than 5 choices, so wanted to play it safe. But, you are correct--OP, you don't need that line if there are 5 and only 5 choices.

Comment: Even with more than 5 choices, the CASE statements deal with that :)

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to create a select statement that joins all the tables and returns only the columns you need into one table. Try something like this:

```
select count(a.choice) as choice1_results, count(b.choice) as choice2_results
from students_answers_polls a
inner join students_ansers_polls b on a.couseId = b.courseId
and a.poll = (select choice1 from polls where poll_Id = @poll_ID)
and b.poll = (select choice2 from polls where poll_id = @poll_ID)
```

And so on...